# Buscar registros dos próximos 7 dias em SQL

Tags: sql

Possuo o seguinte SQL

```
SELECT `age`.*, `inte`.`int_nome`, `inte`.`int_cod_unidade`, `set_uni`.`uni_titulo` as set_unidade, `set_cur`.`cur_titulo` as set_curso, `set_sta`.`set_setor` as set_status, `con`.`con_nome` as agendado_por, `ope`.`con_nome` as atendido_por
FROM (`agendamentos` as age)
JOIN `interessados` as inte ON `inte`.`int_cod`=`age`.`age_cod_interessado`
JOIN `unidades` as set_uni ON `set_uni`.`uni_cod`=`inte`.`int_cod_unidade`
JOIN `cursos` as set_cur ON `set_cur`.`cur_cod`=`inte`.`int_cod_curso`
JOIN `setores` as set_sta ON `set_sta`.`set_cod`=`age`.`age_status`
LEFT JOIN `consultoras` as con ON `con`.`con_cod`=`age`.`age_cod_consultora_agendado`
LEFT JOIN `consultoras` as ope ON `ope`.`con_cod`=`age`.`age_cod_consultora_atendido`
WHERE `age`.`age_data_agendado_para` BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE() AND CURRENT_DATE()+7
```

Preciso que retorne registros dos próximos 7 dias, porém, na minha base de dados tenho os seguintes registros:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como eu faço para retornar corretamente, neste exemplo, teria que retornar apenas dois registros que estão dentro do critério.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como você está utilizando um campo do tipo **DATETIME**, precisa **garantir** que todos os registros irão retornar. Para isso concatene o início com ' 00:00:00' e o final com ' 23:59:59', a fim de garantir o primeiro e último momento do dia.

Desta forma, substitua:

```
WHERE `age`.`age_data_agendado_para` BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE() AND CURRENT_DATE()+7
```

Por:

```
WHERE `age`.`age_data_agendado_para` 
    BETWEEN
      concat(CURRENT_DATE(), ' 00:00:00') AND 
      concat(CURRENT_DATE() + INTERVAL 7 DAY, ' 23:59:59')
```

Comment: Apenas uma observação: + INTERVAL 7 DAY coloquei no de baixo, porque são daqui a 7 dias. E deu certo.

Comment: Ajustei! (fiz os testes com dados no passado, alterei - interval por + interval, mas tinha esquecido da ordem.

Comment: Verdade. Ou poderia tirar a hora e usar so a data, fazendo isso:
cast (`age`.`age_data_agendado_para` as date) between CURRENT_DATE() AND CURRENT_DATE()+7

Comment: É que no meu caso, eu uso o timestamp pra controle de hora também, pra saber que horário está agendado,por este motivo, deu certinho a resposta do Allan

Comment: Verdade @GabrielLocalhost, teria só que testar se mudaria alguma coisa na performance, mas acho uma alternativa válida também.

Comment: Então usa 'Current_timestamp', eu acho que isso removeria a necessidade de concatenação

Answer (score 2):

Altere esse parte:

```
BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE()+7 AND CURRENT_DATE()
```

Por isso:

```
BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE AND CURRENT_DATE() + 7
```

seria a partir de hoje até hoje mais 7 dias, acho que voce se confundiu na ordem das datas

Comment: Mesma coisa. :/